# What is this Z symbol on the PCB?

Tags: pcb, inverter, symbol

Does anyone know what this Z component symbol is? It was in my solar charger inverter and went up in smoke.

[image]

Comment: That board looks to have suffered some rather extreme damage due to the failure of MOV5.  Regardless of whether there is more wrong with this board (likely), consider why this component would have failed in the first place.  Is the solar charge inverter being used outside of specifications, was there a fault elsewhere, etc.  This failure was likely systemic, meaning it was caused from something else.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was caused by trying to charge some very dead lead acid batteries using a generator. The MOV is connected to the circuit controlling the optional mains input supply.

Answer (score 13):

As to what reads next to the component, the symbol is for a MOV, or metal oxide varistor.

The component protects from overvoltage surges and it degrades every time it needs to do work. So when they get old they can increase their leakage current and may fail short so they tend to go up in smoke like you witnessed.

Comment: Thanks. As I said above, I was trying to charge some lead acid batteries using a generator at the time. I expect the supply was really spikey. Its a shame there was nothing left to give me an idea of the original component :-)

Comment: I believe there is usually a fuse upstream of the MOV to protect the MOV when it shorts out a spike. You may find that replacing the fuse "repairs" your board but you should also add a new MOV for future spike protection.

Answer (score 10):

The symbol is a less commonly used one for a MOV or Metal Oxide Varistor.  That coupled with the reference designator of MOV5 seems to confirm it to me.